# Meteor mongo issue in multiple svg rendering

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Below is the summary of my code

```
posts = new Meteor.Collection "post"    

if Meteor.isClient
  Template.canvas.visualize = ->
    logs = posts.find().fetch()
    [.... svg() rendering based on logs....]

if Meteor.isServer
```

I need to use the jsonArray, "logs", to do the svg() rendering. However, this approach will re-render the svg each time. If I hardcoded the logs with fixed jsonarray, e.g. [{"name":"test","x":1, "y":1}, {"name":"test2","x":2, "y":2}, {"name":"test3","x":1, "y":1}], it only renders svg one time. However, if I use .find().fetch() above, it seems like the logs length will change over the time and make the re-rendering issue happen. Is this issue caused by the mongodbs sync between the server and client side? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions form a reactive context, so changes to reactive data sources (such as database queries) will cause them to execute again. In other words, yes the data is being synced to the client and the client is re-rendering. If you don't want this to happen, you can just make your query non-reactive:

```js
var logs = posts.find({}, {reactive: false}).fetch();
```

---

One other thing you could try is setting a session variable when the posts are marked as ready. Here we'll assume that `autopublish` is off, and the server has a publish function called `allPosts`.

```coffee
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'allPosts', ->
      Session.set 'logs', posts.find().fetch()

  Template.canvas.visualize = ->
    logs = Session.get 'logs'

if Meteor.isServer 
  Meteor.publish 'allPosts', ->
    posts.find ranking: $lte: 3
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I think that's the main reason that whenever the data is synced over time, such sync will cause the template's reactivity. Very good point. However, putting "{reactive: false}" makes the "logs" become empty and won't be synced with more data :-(

Comment: If the logs are an empty array, then the template code is running before the data is synced the first time. If you are using iron-router, you could add a `waitOn` for the posts subscription and then this would work.

Comment: I added another idea to the answer.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the tips. I tried to follow your second suggestion, however, it seems to warn me about "Can't find variable: c". Did i miss something here?

Comment: I updated the answer again with a tested solution. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I'd like to make sure that on the server side, i should put: 
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
      Meteor.publish "allPosts", ->
        posts.find({"ranking":{"$lte":3}})

Comment: because with what i mentioned right above, after applying your method, for "console.log logs", i got "undefinied". Any idea about what i missed?

Comment: To note, I reloaded the page, once in a long while, i might see the result (just sometimes, not too often). I also did rememeber to set "autopublish" off. Many thanks!

Comment: Updated with the server code. If it doesn't work with those changes, then I think something else is wrong with your code, and I'd recommend reading [discovermeteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) to learn more about how these pieces fit together.

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for the help!! I tried again but still with no luck. I guess i might need to start from scratch then. But there's one thing really interesting. If i put 'posts = new Meteor.Collection "post" ' outside 'if Meteor.isClient' and 'if Meteor.isServer'. First time, the page won't work. But if i commented out 'posts = new Meteor.Collection "post"', the system might restart itself with the correct result. (But reloading again will make the page fail. Only works right after I commet that part out)